# Inconvenientes con función en google chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe

Se tiene la siguiente funcion en javascript, la cual me permite un php que este contiene otros php que me debe de mostrar los datos de unas consultas

Funcion

```
    echo utf8_decode("<script language='JavaScript'> 

  function recargar()
  {
    prueba_frame_2();
  }

  function prueba_frame_2()
  {
   ajaxinternodos3='<IFRAME src=\"principal_tree.php\" width=\"980\" height=\"17650\" scrolling=\"auto\" frameborder=\"1\"></IFRAME>';

   document.getElementById('contenedorgeneral_2').innerHTML =ajaxinternodos3;

 }


 </script> 

 <br><font class='label'><b>Resultado de la consulta:</font></b><br>
 <div id='contenedorgeneral_2'>
 </div>");
```

archivo principal_tree.php

```
echo '</head>
<frameset cols="3%,17%,*" border="0.1"   id="f1" framespacing="0.1" >

<frame src="control_frame.php"     id="f5" marginheight="0" >

<frameset rows="3%,*" border="0.1"   id="f2" framespacing="0.1" >

    <frame src="archivo_2.php"     id="f3" marginheight="0" >

     <frame src="archivo_3.php"   id="f4" marginheight="0" >

</frameset>

<frame src="archivo_5.php"     id="f5"  name="f5" marginheight="0" >

</frameset>

<noframes>Se?r Usuario su explorador web no soporta frames</noframes>
</html>
' ;
```

pero en google crhome no permite cargar el archivo_5 y el archivo_2
e intentado cambiarlo a iframe pero tampoco lo permite

pero si se realiza la consulta en internet explorer funciona correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se realizo la validación y ya logre que cargara la consulta, pero el php principal_tree no me retorna al principal que principal.php.  </script> 

 <br><font class='label'><b>Resultado de la consulta:</font></b><br>
 <div id='contenedorgeneral_2'>
 </div>"); en contenedorgenerar.... deberia traer la información